# Prime powers with same digits in base $10$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider two prime powers $p^{a}$ and $q^{b}$ having the same multiset of digits in base ten with $p\neq q$ and $\min(a,b)>1$. Does one necessarily have $\{p,q\}=\{2,5\}$?

This is what I and a friend have tried:

- try to prove that the reciprocals of the two numbers are decimal
- use the fact that numbers with same digits are congruent modulo $9$
- try to prove that $p.q\equiv 1\pmod 9$ (edit: I'm somehow thinking about considering the Frobenius automorphism in $\mathbb{F}_{9}$)

We did not manage to answer the question. Can you help us?

Comment: I can't thin' of why base $10$ should be special, so perhaps look for examples in other, smaller bases to see if there are example where the primes don't divide the base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $169,961$ is a counterexample. I doubt there’s anything particularly nice here outside your current observations.

Comment: I would think the number of n-digit squares of primes might grow faster than the number of multi sets of n digits. (Just a guess, not sure).

Comment: No. There’s around $\sqrt{n}\log{n}/2$ primes less than $\sqrt{n}$ and $(n+9)C9=O(n^9)$ multisets of length $n$, so they are nowhere close.

Comment: Don't you mean $\frac{2\sqrt{n}}{\log n}$?

Comment: Yep, doesn’t change the result.